# Do the x264 encoder and image colorspace types need to be the same?

Tags: c, x264

Do the `i_csp` fields in `x264_image_t` and `x264_param_t` have to be the same? What happens if they aren't the same?

Comment: The decoder may apply the incorrect color correction/conversion.

Answer (score 1):

They don't need to be exactly the same but they should be of the same subsampling (4:2:0/4:2:2/4:4:4). That is because libx264 wouldn't make real colorspace conversions but only change memory layout internally to NV12/NV16/I444.

So if you set x264_param_t.i_csp to X264_CSP_I420 you can set x264_image_t.i_csp to any from X264_CSP_I420, X264_CSP_YV12, X264_CSP_NV12, X264_CSP_NV21.

And if you set x264_param_t.i_csp to X264_CSP_I444 you can set x264_image_t.i_csp to any from X264_CSP_I444, X264_CSP_YV24 and even X264_CSP_BGR, X264_CSP_BGRA, X264_CSP_RGB but than you will need to correctly set i_colmatrix/b_fullrange yourself or better use X264_CSP_BGR for x264_param_t.i_csp.

Comment: Is this documented?

Comment: As much as anything in libx264 i.e. source code is the documentation. If you are interested you can read the code of [x264_frame_copy_picture](http://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi?p=x264.git;a=blob;f=common/frame.c;hb=HEAD#l366), [x264_frame_new](http://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi?p=x264.git;a=blob;f=common/frame.c;hb=HEAD#l72) and [x264_frame_internal_csp](http://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi?p=x264.git;a=blob;f=common/frame.c;hb=HEAD#l45) functions.